# CLC filter calculator for 24VDC switching PSU

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, filter, noise

I want to filter the DC output of a switching power supply with a CLC filter circuit.

The PSU is a good quality MeanWell one I am using in an audio amplifier unit, noise floor (hum + hiss) is too much when amplification is dramatic and I know it is coming from the PSU because the old one that was previously installed in the unit was almost dead silent. Hum and hiss is audible at -40dBu when the amplification is at +20dBu when before nothing was hearable.

The power rail I want to filter is a simple 24VDC, 1.1 amp output from the power supply (Mean Well RS-25-24).

How can I calculate the components values I need for my circuit?

[image: PSU installation]

Comment: Have you tried an AC simulation in Spice?

Comment: @JonathanS. I'm fairly new to this, what would be an AC simulation? Does that mean I need to filter the PSU's input?

Comment: Why do you think it is fixable with a filter, what if the power supply is different, or installed differently from the original? Did the original supply have floating or earthed output? Did the origlinal supply have non-grounded or grounded mains inlet? Was the original supply mounted  to same metal chassis? How did you install the new supply?

Comment: @Justme I have installed the new PSU exactly where the other was, and it is grounded to the same (and only ground point) to the chassis where the PSU ground and inlet ground meet

Comment: Yeah, but how? Theres three wires coming in from mains plug, connected to where exactly? And the MeanWell output is floating, not ground-referenced. Was the original supply output also floating or ground-referenced.

Comment: Spice is a program that lets you simulate circuits, such as your filter. On Windows, LTSpice is likely the easiest to use. You can run a so-called AC simulation that lets you examine your filter's characteristics quite easily - for example, you can let Spice show you a graph of the filter's frequency response. That way you can first eyeball some component values, and then tweak the filter until you're happy with it. You'll likely have to add damping networks, too, to prevent ringing. These are hard to design without a simulator. (And don't forget to account for the caps' and inductors' ESR).

Comment: If you *truly believe* that this DC supply is injecting audio noise into the amplifier via its DC connection, then your CLC low-pass filter should have significant attenuation over the whole audio range. Rejection of -20 dB at 20 Hz will result in VERY LARGE component values for C & L. Prepare to be disappointed. As @Justme has pointed out, there are often other noise-injecting paths that should be considered first before resorting to your proposed solution. You may find that the fix is far less radical and easily implemented.

Comment: Was your old one a SMPS, too? Hum is often caused by mains frequency leakage which is rather large in SMPS. Usual ground-referenced audio is a terrible design that is vulnerable to this.

Comment: @tobalt Old PSU was linear indeed..

Comment: @Justme I have edited the post with the new PSU installation

Comment: @glen_geek Added a picture of the new psu's wiring

Comment: The power supply is not bolted on to metal chassis, but sitting on glass insulation? Then it is not correctly mounted. Where do the connection wires go to? It's still unclear if the problem is simply your new supply having a floating output if it the old one was ground referenced.

Comment: @Justme Isolated from the chassis on the glass panel indeed, as the old PSU was. Any easy way to try to connect the PSU's casing to the metal chassis to check if that's the issue?

Comment: @Wizzardzz Sorry I was a bit hasty - **usually** MeanWell metal cased PSU modules read in their manuals that it must be bolted tight to a grounded metal chassis. I could not find that, it simply mentions the FG terminal must go to mains earth/ground (i.e. directly or almost directly to mains plug wiring). The floatingness of the output may or may not be the issue. Have you got the grounded mains plug connected to a grounded mains outlet? In some countries and old houses you can plug a grounded plug into ungrounded socket.

Comment: @Justme yes, Meanwell's data sheet includes **Note #6**:  *All the EMC tests are been executed by mounting the unit on a 360mm by 360mm metal plate with 1mm of thickness*.

Answer (score 1):

Filtering your power rails with a CLC filter won't do you much good because the problem is likely common-mode noise.

Your new supply is a SMPS, which typically leak up to ~mAs of mains frequency current to the DC side. This current will flow back to earth through your other equipment, such as audio interface. This will generate the notorious hum.

There are a few options here:

- Short your negative DC side directly to the earth pin of the SMPS. This provides a short route back to earth.
- Get a medical grade SMPS, a linear PSU or follow up your new AC/DC SMPS converter with another isolated DC/DC converter. All of this will reduce/eliminate mains frequency leakage to your equipment ground.
- Even though the mains current loop goes through capacitors (in the SMPS), it still is a mains ground loop. Place audio isolation transformers in a convenient place to break that ground loop. Where this is would depend on the full schematics of your stuff.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation and proposed solutions, I will try them out tomorrow and report back!